# Google Sheets IMPORTXML getRange and setRange bad "values"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I use a Google sheet and do an importXML to grab house pricing from Zillow.  The cell has the following formula:

```
=VALUE(IMPORTXML(FirstQuotedTextStringInFormula("F4"),"//div[contains(@class, 'zestimate primary-quote')]/div/text()[3]"))
```

You can see the FirstQuotedStringInFormula allows me to save the URL in a different cell.

I use an app script to capture this data for history tracking on the price.

```
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
  var source = sheet.getRange("B2:AC2");
  var values = source.getValues();
  sheet.insertRowBefore(3);
  sheet.getRange(3, 2, 1, 28).setValues([values[0]]);
};
```

This works fine for all of the values I am pulling in.  The only ones that don't work are the ones that are pulling values from the cells that have the IMPORTXML formula.  When I try to pull in that data to the history sheet, the link to it "=Assets!B6" works fine.  The value is shown as expected.  But when I run the script above, the value shows up in the next row as "#VALUE!"  Just that shows up in the cell as standard text.  Any idea where this is breaking?

EDIT:
I tried to replicate the issue in a sample spreadsheet and I can't get the issue to pop up using a generic link (to avoid using personal data).

In the sheet, I set Sheet2!B2 with the following:

```
=VALUE(IMPORTXML("https://homedepot.com/p/206651614", "//span[@id='ajaxPrice']/@content"))
```

This is working fine.  If you look at the History tab, I can use the new menu ("Manage") to snapshot the values and the values in row 2 are placed in row 3.  It works fine.  If I replace the above with:

```
=VALUE(IMPORTXML(FirstQuotedTextStringInFormula("F4"),"//div[contains(@class, 'zestimate primary-quote')]/div/text()[3]"))
```

Then when I go to snapshot the value in the history tab, it puts #VALUE! in the cell instead.  I have also tried replacing my "FirstQuotedTextStringInFormula("F4") with the actual URL and it still does the same thing.  What is different between these 2 that could be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.  I do not know why or how it solves the problem, but it may just be an over complexity issue.  I replaced the original IMPORTXML call with an IMPORTXML call that pulls from the Zillow API.  I followed this as an example and now the automation works fine.

https://www.reddit.com/r/sheets/comments/93hjxx/find_real_estate_value_zillow_zestimate_or/